# What was the highest use of raw strength used by Rogue?

Tags: marvel, powers, rogue

What was the highest use of raw strength used by Rogue, using only the strength stolen from Ms. Marvel?

As "highest use of raw strength" I mean:

- Defeat someone who can take a large amount of damage. E.g.: Hulk, Juggernaut;
- Lift something VERY heavy. E.g.: An airplane, one building, etc.

Comment: "incredible" seems a bit opinion-based; would you have a clearer definition for it? :)

Comment: @Jenayah YES. what would you use?

Comment: Well - your question, your rules I guess :) Just warning you that I reckon some people might vote to close your question as primarily opinion-based. Off the hat - you could provide an instance of a "lesser" use of raw strength, then ask if in the same condition/comics arc, there was double the amount of damage dealt or something. I'd suggest taking a look at [Guidelines for great subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Just some suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

## Defeating Captain America.

In *Avengers Annual #10*, Rogue absorbs the powers of Ms. Marvel and beats the ever-living crap out of Captain America, while walking away unscathed. (All we really see of the fight is its aftermath, but it's heavily implied that she beat him through sheer strength.)

[image: Rogue vs Cap]

---

She doesn't stop there, though.  Once she has Cap's powers, she goes on to beat Thor.

[image: Rogue vs Thor]

Then, with *Thor's* powers, she beats The Vision-- with one punch.

[image: Rogue vs Vision]

Comment: Taking out Cap doesn't necessarily require immense strength. When fighting an opponent with vastly superior strength, Cap usually wins by speed and agility (avoiding the opponent's attacks), and tactics/strategy (getting the opponent angry, so he can trick them into doing something that hurts them, that sort of thing). If Cap wasn't on the lookout for Rogue (and I don't think he was, in this story), the flight power she stole from Carol would probably be more key in her victory. Note that she "caught [him] off-guard."

Comment: And, wrt Thor, she didn't beat him physically - she took his powers before he did more than catch her by reflex. And, by the time she punched Vision, as you note yourself, she *had* Thor's strength, so she obviously didn't beat him with just the Ms. Marvel power set.

Comment: Right. I wasn't trying to say that she beat Thor with strength alone, and the OP specified "using only the strength stolen from Ms. Marvel," so I didn't mention Thor or the Vision in my short answer.  I just thought it was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Rogue's most impressive feat of strength against an inanimate object was probably the time she stopped a train in [Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 #218](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_218).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Her most impressive strength showing against a living being was probably the time she defeated [Strong Guy](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Guido_Carosella_(Earth-616)) in a gladiatorial match in [Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 #278](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_278).

[image]

[image]

[image]